# Best way to represent a 4d table in database (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, normalization

I'm developing an financial application that does scenario analysis for a bunch of securities. The "scenarios" are very straight forward, they take certain inputs (in my case, two in particular, say A and B) and "shock" them (i.e. multiply 10%, 20%, 30%, etc.) then compute the outputs (I have about 20 different output metrics).

This results in a 4-d table where:

1. x-axis is the shocks of input A (10%A, 20%A, 30%A, etc)
2. y-axis is the shocks of input B (10%B, 20%B, 30%B, etc)
3. z-axis is the 20 different output metrics
4. w-axis is the different securities

I'd like to persist this table into a database (oracle). The way I did this was to have 2 tables:

1. `Table S` for shocks levels (percents) of inputs
2. `Table O` for security vs output

Here is the way each table looks like:

```
 Table S
 -------------------------
 shock_id    shock_value
 0           0%
 1           10%
 2           20%
 3           30%
 4           40%
 ...   ...

 Table O
 --------------------------
 security_id   A_shock_id   B_shock_id   output_1   output_2 
 1             0            0            1.2        2.3
 1             1            0            1.34       3.52
 1             2            0            2.4        3.98
 1             3            0            3.42       5.31
 1             4            0            23.2       133.1
 1             0            1            2.2        32.1
 1             0            2            23.1       4.2
 1             0            3            ...        ...
 ...           ...          ...          ...        ...
```

Basically I've flattened out the 4-d table having the PK for `Table O` be `(security_id, A_shock_id, B_shock_id)` where `A_shock_id` and `B_shock_id` are FKs to `Table S`. The obvious shortcoming of this way is that it is not flexible if I want to add other shockable inputs (since the shocked inputs are hardcoded as columns).

Is there a more flexible/standard way to represent data such as this? Or is this a limitation of normalized databases?

Comment: You said, "Basically I've flattened out the 4-d table by introducing 2 foreign keys..." No, you haven't. There's essentially no difference between your "flattened" structure, and a structure that uses shock values (0.10, 0.20, etc., I presume) directly in "Table O".

Comment: Good point, ty. Edited to actually say what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether this is a limitation or feature of relational databases is definitely an open question.  But, yes, relational databases are intended to map "known" data into tables/sets with relationships between them.  Most projects involving relational databases start with data modeling, as either a formal or informal step in the process.

The problem that you pose easily maps to relational technology.  You are just too fixated on the output of the results.  You seem to have two types of inputs:

- Securities
- Adjustable parameters

And 20 output metrics.

You should encode the adjustable parameters the same way that you do the output metrics, as a table with different columns.  The parameter sets table would start with two columns:  Shock_A and Shock_B.  I would also include a "type" column so you know to expect exactly these two parameters.  Adding additional variables is as easy as adding a column into this table.

This structure is not purely normalized.  One type of relationship that maps poorly into most SQL engines is the one-of relationship  The parameter sets are an example of this.  The "type" column with different parameters is an adequate way to represent this structure.

Comment: To check if I understood you correctly. The "parameters table" you are talking about, would that be a semi-static table that defines the different permutations of the shocks on the different parameters (each row can be thought of as a vector that defines the shock value on each coordinate which represents how much each parameter has bee shocked)? Then the output table's PK can be `(security_id, row_in_parameter_table)`. Adding a new parameter to shock would be as simple as adding a new column (with default value of 0) and inserting the new permutations.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly.  The parameter sets are an object and should be modeled as such.  You will have to modify the parameter sets table to add new parameters.  (You could normalize these, but that might be normalization step too far for such rarely changing attributes.)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be that of completely normalize the schema, categorizing input types by means of an `InputTypes` table with columns `Id` and `Description`.
In your case the table would show like this:

```
Table InputTypes
-----------------------
Id   Description
0    A
1    B
...
```

In another table `ShockCombinations` you could have different shock combinations like these:

```
Table ShockCombinations
-----------------------------
Id InputType_Id ShockValue
1  0            10%
1  1            20%
2  0            0%
2  1            10%
....
```

In the table `OutputTypes` you could have different output types:

```
Table OutputTypes
-----------------------------
Id Description
1  Output1
2  Output2
....
```

Such way the table `O` could have the following structure:

```
Table O
--------------------------
security_id   ShockCombination_id   OutputType_id Values 
1             1                     1             1.2
1             1                     2             2.3
1             2                     1             1.34
1             2                     2             1.77
...
```

This way there is no limit in the number of input combinations and output you can deal with and you can easily add new input types, combinations of them and outputs with no modifications to your schema.

Comment: What if I were to have more than one input that I can "shock"? Your solution definitely works for what I've asked above. Just curious on how you would go about adding more shocked inputs (i.e. adding dimension to the output table). What if I were to have A,B,C shocked inputs? The output table will now be 5 dimensional.

Comment: I didn't perfectly get your need, I've edited my answer to show you a more appropriate model, I hope now having provided a correct and suitable schema.

Comment: This makes it clear, ty! Somewhat similar to what is suggested above.